# Sitecore Analytics Robots Exclusion

Tags: session, analytics, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

We are using Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 and DMS 2.0.1 rev.120427. We are using CoveoEnterpriseSearch in our application. The problem is whenever there is a visit to a page, 3 unnecessary rows are inserting in analytics databse (pages table with url '/Coveo/Anonymous/').

Settings in `Sitecore.Analytics`.Config related to robots are,

```
 <setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots" value="true" />
 <setting name="Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots" value="true" />
 <setting name="Analytics.Robots.IgnoreAutoRobots" value="true" />
```

How could I stop inserting of those records? We've tried placing user agent 'Coveo Sitecore Crawler' under `<excludedUserAgents>` tag in Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.Config. And we created a 'robots.txt' file in the root with Coveo user-agent & Disallow options with no use.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a bug, I'd suggest to try contacting Sitecore support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict tracking of Coveo URL's by adding `/Coveo/Anonymous/` to `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` settings in `web.config`.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 rev. 121009 (6.5.0 Update-6) and DMS 2.0.1 rev. 121009 which was released in in October 18, 2012

> Engagement Analytics
>
> The system did not discard requests that come
> from robots based on the information in the
> "/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config" file.
> (355803)